# SoapUI- How to assert from a response

Tags: assert, soapui

I am new to SoapUI I have a basic question. When i get a response to a services i would like to do an assert for a value. below is scripts i had created under Script Assertion

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def holder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
assert holder["//ConstraintId[0]"] =="5000006";

I get the following error:
assert holder["//ConstraintId[0]"] =="5000006" | | | | [] false com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder@8b6500 (toString() threw java.lang.NullPointerException)

**********************************************************
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler

def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
assert rootNode.Body.Constraintid[0].text=="5000006";

I get the following error:
assert rootNode.Body.Constraintid[0].text=="5000006" | | | | | | | | | | | false | | | | groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren@17a5c01 (toString() == "") | | | groovy.util.slurpersupport.NoChildren@2e80e1 (toString() == "") | | groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren@10f682f (toString() == "") | 

Response
   <soap:Body>
      <GetEnumResponse xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/">
         <GetEnumResult>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <StatusId>0</StatusId>
         </GetEnumResult>
         <enumsInformation>
            <EnumInformation>
               <TransactionId>0</TransactionId>
               <ConstraintId>5000006</ConstraintId>
               <EnumValue>abc</EnumValue>
               <Index>10</Index>
            </EnumInformation>
         </enumsInformation>
      </GetEnumResponse>
   </soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Was able to find the solution.  Namespace is decalared before using getNodeValue.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def holder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)

holder.namespaces["tal"]="http://www.xyz.com/"
def node = holder.getNodeValue("//tal:ConstraintId[1]");
log.info(node);
assert node == "5000006";

<soap:Body>
      <GetEnumResponse xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/">
         <GetEnumResult>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <StatusId>0</StatusId>
         </GetEnumResult>
         <enumsInformation>
            <EnumInformation>
               <TransactionId>0</TransactionId>
               <ConstraintId>5000006</ConstraintId>
               <EnumValue>xyz</EnumValue>
               <Index>10</Index>
            </EnumInformation>
         </enumsInformation>
      </GetEnumResponse>
   </soap:Body>
```